# How to limit the Alfresco query result set to Top-N rows only

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I need how to get 20 records out of 100 from alfresco in java.

**Query:**

```
+@cm\:categories:"*categoryId*"+TYPE:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content
```

Here In this categoryId 100 records in alfresco. But I need top 20 records.
Please help me.

Comment: How are you doing the query? What interface / code / etc? (Page sizing differs)

Comment: @WebParam(name = "query", targetNamespace = "http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/repository/1.0")
        org.alfresco.webservice.types.Query query,

Comment: You should edit your question and paste in the exact java code, a small snippet in a comment isn't really enough!